# Parse nested json array from a file

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a json file `sample.json` containing a json array as follows:

```
[
{
  "time": "2021-01-04T00:11:32.362Z",
  "extra_data": {
    "id": "123"
  },
  "info": "event123"
},
{
  "time": "2021-01-05T00:11:32.362Z",
  "extra_data": {
    "id": "456"
  },
  "info": "event456"
},
{
  "time": "2021-01-06T00:11:32.362Z",
  "extra_data": {
    "id": "789"
  },
  "info": "event789"
}
]
```

I am trying to unmarshal this json array so that for each json object (i.e. event), I can access the `id` and `info` values. This is what I have so far:

```
func main() {

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/janedoe/Downloads/sample.json")
    var events Event
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &events)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(events))
    // Reading each value by its key for each event
    fmt.Println("Event123_Time :", events.Timestamp,
            "\nEvent123_ExtraData_Id :", events.ExtraData.Id,
            "\nEvent123_Info :", events.Info)
} 
type Event struct {
    Time string `json:"time"`
    ExtraData ExtraData `json:"extra_data"`
    Info string `json:"info"`
}

type ExtraData struct {
     Id string   `json:"id"`
}
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
main.Event
Event123_Time :  
Event123_ExtraData_Id :
Event123_Info :
```

I am not getting any values, implying that the marshalling is not happening as expected. How can I fix this?

Comment: Unmarshal into a slice.

Comment: Also always check errors. `json.Unmarshal` returns an error - which you are not capturing - which invariably shows the unmarshal operation has failed.

Answer (score 2):

Since your json is an array, I think you want:

```golang
var events []Event
```

not

```golang
var events Event
```

Here's a version with that change:

```golang
func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/janedoe/Downloads/sample.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var events []Event
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &events); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(events))
    for i, event := range events {
        // Reading each value by its key for each event
        fmt.Println(i, "Event123_Time :", event.Time,
            "\nEvent123_ExtraData_Id :", event.ExtraData.Id,
            "\nEvent123_Info :", event.Info)
    }
}

type Event struct {
    Time      string    `json:"time"`
    ExtraData ExtraData `json:"extra_data"`
    Info      string    `json:"info"`
}

type ExtraData struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}
```